# CSS don't work on wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-pdf

I'm using the wicked_pdf and I have a problem. The css don't work. How use correctly?

My code is this:

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>WickedPdfExample</title>
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.min.css" -%>
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application.css" -%>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**layouts/pdf.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>PDF</title>
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap" -%>
</head>
<body>

  <div class='container'>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**customers_controller.erb**

```
  def index
    @customers = Customer.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => 'file_name',
        :layout => 'layouts/pdf.html.erb'
        :template => 'customers/index.pdf.erb',
        :show_as_html => params[:debug].present?
      end
    end
  end
```

**index.pdf.erb**

```
<h1>Listing Customers</h1>

<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Cpf</th>
      <th>Occupation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @customers.each do |customer| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= customer.name %></td>
        <td><%= customer.cpf %></td>
        <td><%= customer.occupation %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And sometimes, get this error:

undefined method `start_with?' for nil:NilClass

What I 'm making wrong?

But, my bootstrap don't charge. I tried ALL!!!

Comment: I see that a lot recently. Apparently it is caused by one of your `url(.*)` in your css files. Any chance your project is open source so I could debug it more deeply (as I seriously struggle to even imagine a scenario when the code in wicked_pdf gem could fail).

Comment: For reference, there is an open issue: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/470

Comment: This is the git: https://github.com/eltonsantos/wicked_pdf_example please, pull request this. I tried all, but nothing worked!

Comment: It works for me. :( Which ruby version are you using?

Comment: ruby 2.3.0, rails 4.2.5 =l

Comment: Still works with ruby 2.3.0. What operating system? (i seriously not sure what could cause it, the code seems pretty much ok).

Comment: (Do you mind doing sth quite epic? We culd pair remotely to resolve that once for all, lets wait for chat option to show up?)

Comment: Sure, add on gtalk or skype (@eltin182).

Comment: Sorry, but I like keeping my personal channels personal (taught by experience). If you happen to have gmail account we can connect over hangout - my email is in my profile.

Comment: Ok, I will add you on gtalk for connect hangout, this weekend, ok? Thanks man!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got my CSS working by this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://#{request.host_with_port}/#{asset_path("application.css")}", rel: "stylesheet", media: "all" %>
```